# How can i find and exclude outliers in each day?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like the below:

```
price,date
14570,2/5/2017
14570,2/5/2017
14570.001,2/5/2017
14570.001,2/5/2017
14570.001,2/5/2017
14570.001,2/5/2017
25149.57,2/5/2017
24799.68,2/5/2017
24799.68,2/5/2017
14600,2/6/2017
14600,2/6/2017
2563000,2/6/2017
14600,2/6/2017
14800,2/6/2017
14800,2/6/2017
14600,2/6/2017
50,2/6/2017
14600,2/6/2017
14600,2/6/2017
```

I want to find and exclude outliers in each day.
so i try to use the below snippet code:

```
order_items = order_items[np.abs(order_items['price']-order_items['price'].mean()) <= (3*order_items['price'].std())]
# keep only the ones that are within +3 to -3 standard deviations in the column 'Data'.

order_items = order_items[~(np.abs(order_items['price']-order_items['price'].mean()) > (3*order_items['price'].std()))]
```

The code find the outliers in all data not daily. How do i find and exclude outliers daily?

Comment: @mozway This is my question that i commented you it in the past question

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with `mean` and `std`:

```
order_items = order_items[np.abs(order_items['price']-order_items.groupby('date')['price'].transform('mean')) <= (3*order_items.groupby('date')['price'].transform('std'))]
```